# Necessary rules for ufw

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have installed ufw, enabled it, and added one rule - ufw deny from A.B.C.D (just an IP from a blacklist). Was working OK, but now can't connect to my raspberry.

Did I forget some special rule to allow all other connections?

Comment: Connect how? SSH? HTTP?

Comment: Nothing basically. SSH and VNC was not working before reboot. Disabled FW.